# Battery Icon does not work properly for dual batteries

Tags: power-management, battery

I have two batteries for my laptop, one is the built-in battery and the other comes from keyboard (X1 Helix if you want to know how that works). The way it works is: laptop draws power from bat1(keyboard bettery) first, until it's below 5%, then draws from bat0(build-in battery) until it's gone too.

The problem being: 
    first, it does not combine two batteries into one display, say if bat1 is 10% and bat0 is 100%, it doesn't show 55%, it shows an almost empty bat1 on battery icon. 
    Second even when bat1 is gone and bat0 is providing power, the default displayed battery status on icon bar is still that of bat1, which is empty, and that bothers me a lot because I have to click on the battery display and manually check how much I have left on bat0.

Any one can help?

Comment: i would imagine that in order to obtain the desired functionality, it would have to be implemented by a 3rd party battery monitor, or implemented by the developers of the battery monitor your using. the best thing i could think to do would to have a separate monitor for each battery, or to have them both used in parallel. but since this is such a rare scenario i don’t think you will be able to have this functionality without someone recoding something

Comment: Similarly, for my Dell 15 7537. (See also "http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154104/battery-meter-only-appears-when-laptop-gets-plugged-in/187636#187636".)